# Vagrant - provision guest in same virtualbox as host?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a windows host machine. I run Vagrant on that box to spin up a VirtualBox guest  (master) ubuntu machine. From inside master, I want to run Vagrant with an Ansible provisioner to create and provision 3 slave ubuntu machines.

I have read other posts indicating that the master could run VirtualBox within itself, but that those machines would be 32-bit machines, and I need them to be 64-bit.

Is it in any way possible for the windows host to run VirtualBox and for the master guest node to create VMs within that host VirtualBox, i.e. all VMs are guests of the windows host?

Many thanks,

Dave

Comment: Does multi machine setup help? https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/

Comment: @taskinoor that's what I'm using in order to create the 3 slaves. But they would all be created as 32 bit within a VirtualBox instance within the master VM. I want them to be peers of the master - with the master and slaves running in the same VirtualBox running in Windows - so the host for the master and slaves is the Windows one.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it in any way possible for the windows host to run VirtualBox and for the master guest node to create VMs within that host VirtualBox, i.e. all VMs are guests of the windows host?

Yes - Its not well supported but it is working. There are some issues with networking (make sure to use 2 different range set of IPs) but overall it works

Now for 64 bits VM, this is related to [Nested Virtualization: VT-in-VT ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) which has not been fixed (as of today at least) so you cannot have a 64bits VM running inside a VirtualBox VM.

From what I know, people on VMWare were able to make it work with 64 bits (did not try myself)